# How to move to the middle of the remaining sentence?

Tags: macos, hotkeys

On a Mac, when you are going through texts and sentence, (for example in an editor like Atom), I know that the hotkey combo: command + right direct key will get me to the end of a sentence.

looks like this ('|' indicate where you are at):

123|456789 >>> 123456789|

Is there a way to get to the middle of the remaining sentence?

like this:

123|456789 >>> 123456|789

Someitmes I have a long sentence in iTerm or Atom or in chrome address bar and I want to go to middle to edit text and it will be super helpful if I can binary-ly jump in sentence.

Even more can we apply the same concept vertically? for example in a webpage, jump to the middle; in a file, jump to the middle line.

I want to ask if this command is built-in in Mac. If not, how can I get it.

Thank in advanced!

Comment: Use your mouse or learn to navigate quicker by e.g. using Ctrl+Arrow to jump whole words. Personally I don't know of any shortcut that would allow you jump tot he center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In your example, no, there is no regular shortcut can do that.**

Because `123456789` is technically just a word (words are separated by spaces between them), and to jump to each word, you can use <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>.

So `Lorem| ipsum dolor sit amet` with one <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> will get you to `Lorem ipsum| dolor sit amet`

You can easily find some [Navigation shortcuts](http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/23/keyboard-shortcuts-to-navigate-select-text-mac-os-x/) to boost your work performance.

**But if you want to jump to the middle of the sentence in Atom**, there is [vim-mode-plus](https://github.com/t9md/atom-vim-mode-plus) which transform your Atom into Vim editor, and, then, you can use all vim shortcuts to move around your text.

Eg: <kbd>4</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to go right 4 characters.

`1|23456789` --> `12345|6789`